# What primer for bare wood stairs with nails showing

Tags: paint, stairs, metal, primer, nails

I'm painting the stairs going down to my basement that previously had carpet. After removing the carpet, they are like bare, new wood. Unfortunately, the treads were nailed with common nails (not finish nails) and I cannot set them down enough to fill over because that would probably split the wood. My plan is to drive the nails flush and paint over them. Should I use an oil based primer since it will be going on metal nail heads?

Comment: Consider removing the nails and filling.

Comment: Those nails are probably structural.

Answer (score 1):

They make special paint for stair treads that has anti-slip properties, I would use that. It's typically thick enough top cover the nail heads, but they may work themselves up over time.